How to record/calculate the final velocity of board breaking strikes?
How do you suggest I calculate the final velocity of a board breaking strikes such as a downward kick, or a hammer fist?
Can I find the displacement/ second with a frame by frame analysis from a video, or is the distance the kick is moving too short to be captured accurately with a video format?
Would I have to use a slow motion video?

I recommend checking out what Rhett Allain is doing.
Rhett Allain has made a lot of videos in which a program called 'Tracker' is used to analyse some dynamics taking place.
The tracker software is an open source software project. Tracker requires the Java Runtime Environment as platform.

From the feature set:
Tracking:
Manual and automated object tracking with position, velocity and acceleration overlays and data.


By the looks of it: on youtube there are multiple tutorials for Tracker
